# Collect RDD to one node in sorted order

Tags: apache-spark

I have a large RDD which needs to be written to a single file on disk, one line for each element, the lines sorted in some defined order. So I was thinking of sorting the RDD, collect one partition at a time in the driver, and appending to the output file.

Couple of questions:

1. After `rdd.sortBy()`, do I have the guarantee that partition 0 will contain the first elements of the sorted RDD, partiton 1 will contain the next elements of the sorted RDD, and so on? (I'm using the default partitioner.)
   e.g.

   ```
   val rdd = ???
   val sortedRdd = rdd.sortBy(???)
   for (p <- sortedRdd.partitions) {
     val index = p.index
     val partitionRdd = sortedRdd mapPartitionsWithIndex { case (i, values) => if (i == index) values else Iterator() }
     val partition = partitionRdd.collect()
     partition foreach { e =>
       // Append element e to file
     }
   }
   ```
2. I understand that `rdd.toLocalIterator` is a more efficient way of fetching all partitions, one at a time. So same question: do I get the elements in the order given by `.sortBy()`?

   ```
   val rdd = ???
   val sortedRdd = rdd.sortBy(???)
   for (e <- sortedRdd.toLocalIterator) {
     // Append element e to file
   }
   ```

Comment: Can't you use `saveAsTextFile` instead of looping and appending yourself?

Comment: `saveAsTextFile` generates as many output files as there are partitions.

Comment: BTW, How big is your file?

Comment: Bigger than the memory of any node.